# Using selenium in java I want to click on the "Accept" button of the cookie

Tags: java, selenium, cookies

[image]
Using java selenium I want to press click on the "Accept button". I used locators like: `cssselector`, `xpath`, `relpath`, `tag` and `click()` method, and didn't work.
Second method was to use `DeleteAllCookie` or `DeleteCookieByName`, `AddCoockie`, fetch a cookie and that didn't work.

I think it can be with `Thread.sleep`, but I don't know how to identify the element and I don't know how to write the script so I can click on that "Accept". I think selenium java can't identify that button.

Comment: Always add your code including console output. In case like this page source code is needed to see as well. Please provide html source code or url.

Comment: Can we have the URL if it's public ? otherwise share the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably when you load the webpage, the cookie policy banner is not present yet and it appears a few seconds later. For this reason, when you try to find the element it does not exists.
But do not worry, Selenium has a tool for this, you have to wait programmatically until the element appears, there is the syntax:

```
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 600);
w.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
        By.cssSelector("button[attribute='value']")));

WebElement cookieButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[attribute='value']"));

cookieButton.click()
```

Basically you create a new WebDriverWait instance and pass as arguments the driver and the maximum milliseconds that you want to wait, then you set the wait conditions with the until method using your prefered selector.

Comment: Thank you so much, after many times on google and many attempts, it worked.